# ActiveRecord date-related queries; MySQL versus PostgreSQL

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I have a database of records that I want to select the most recent week of days and group by the day to get the count per day on these records. If I was writing the MySQL query manually, I'd start with something like:

```
SELECT COUNT( id ) AS count, DAY( created_at ) AS the_day
FROM  `results` 
GROUP BY the_day
```

How can I use `ActiveRecord` to abstract this query so that it works for PostgreSQL as well? So, far, I've got a scope to select this query above, but I'm not positive this will work with PostgreSQL:

```
  scope :recent, lambda {
    select(['id', 'COUNT(id) AS the_count', 'DAY(created_at) AS the_day'])
    .where(:created_at => 7.days.ago.utc...Time.now.utc)
    .order('the_day DESC')
    .group('the_day')
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SQL spec provides an extraction method that is DB-agnostic: `EXTRACT(<unit> FROM <date>)`

Comment: This probably works in most environments, however, if you're doing testing using Sqlite3 then it appears that it does not know what to do with ```EXTRACT```.